# Switching Language in C#.NET has no impact to site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have implemented Multi Language Support into my ASP.NET C# followed by [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/586948/ASP-NET-Website-and-Csharp-with-Multi-Language) tutorial and set english to my Default language as can be seen here:

[image: ?lang=en is Default setting]

When switching to german nothing happens:
[image: switched to german has no impact]

In my App_GlobalResource Folder I have to files: 
`de.language.resx` and `en.language.resx`

My mls.cs file (In the tutorial named BasePage.cs) contains the following code:

```
public class mls : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public void setLang() {
        InitializeCulture();
    }
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["lang"]))
        {
            Session["lang"] = Request["lang"];
        }
        string lang = Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]);
        string culture = string.Empty;
         // In case, if you want to set vietnamese as default language, then removing this comment
        if (lang.ToLower().CompareTo("en") == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            culture = "en-US";
        }
        if (lang.ToLower().CompareTo("en") == 0 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            culture = "en-US";
        }
        if (lang.ToLower().CompareTo("de") == 0)
        {
            culture = "de-AT";
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
}
```

And here is my Login.aspx page:

```
public partial class WebForm3 : mls 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(Session["lang"])))
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]) == "en")
            {
                lbl_Debug.Text = "lang=en";
                Session["lang"] = null;
                Session["lang"] = "en";
            }
            else if(Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]) == "de")
            {
                lbl_Debug.Text = "lang=de";
                Session["lang"] = null;
                Session["lang"] = "de";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_Debug.Text = "nothing";
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my aspx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ph_RowMain" runat="server">
<div class="login-box">
    <div class="login-logo">
        <a href="Start.aspx"><b>
            <asp:Literal ID="lt_adminInterfaceHeader" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:en.language, lt_adminHeader%>"></asp:Literal></b></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-logo -->
    <div class="login-box-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">
            <asp:Literal ID="lt_adminInterfaceBox" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:en.language, lt_adminBox%>"></asp:Literal>
        </p>

        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_email" runat="server" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="<%$Resources:en.language,tb_email%>"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_password" runat="server" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="<%$Resources:en.language, tb_password%>"></asp:TextBox>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <asp:Button ID="btn_signIn" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:en.language, btn_signIn%>" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" />
            </div>
            <!-- /.col -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.login-box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->
```

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Can you show the aspx markup?

Comment: @brainlesscoder post updated

Comment: I think you have the name of the files wrong. you have `de.lanuage.rex` but according to the article it requires format `anyname.language.de.resx`

Comment: @brainlesscoder Ha! You're awesome! That was the Problem we are looking for a few hours. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: That's great. Happy to help. But since there is no answer, others with the same issue might be looking for it. I am posting this as answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the name of the files wrong. you have `de.lanuage.rex` but, according to the article you referred, it requires format `anyname.language.de.resx`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to localize your website, name of the resourse files matters a lot.
your resourse files name should follow the below format
 **FileNameYouWant.language-culture.resx**

in case you do not specify the language-culture i.e if your filename is like this
**FileNameyouWant.resx** then by default it will take english language(language-culture='en').

example:German language resourse file name=FileNameYouWant.de.resx
French language resourse file name=FileNameYouWant.fr.resx